# Is there functionality for simultaneous mass editing of images in many documents in Sanity?

Tags: sanity

If I have 600 documents with image "A" but I need to replace all of them with image "B", is there a way for me to do it all at once without manually replacing the image in each document?

I have tried asset plugins like "media browser" but it dosen't seem like they have this kind of functionality.